# Unable to add IPv6 address to sendmail access list

Tags: sendmail, ipv6

I am running Sendmail 8.14.4 on Slackware 13.37. I have the following in my /etc/mail/access file and it works without any errors:

```
Connect:127                   OK
Connect:10.0.1                RELAY   # Net:  office
Connect:50.116.6.8            RELAY   # Host: glider
Connect:96.126.127.87         RELAY   # Host: kite
```

The above configuration also allows me to send an e-mail via IPv6 to a local user on the mail server.  However, it does not allow my office to relay via IPv6. I have tried two ways of adding IPv6 networks to my access file.

Method 1:

```
Connect:127                   OK
Connect:10.0.1                RELAY   # Net:  office
Connect:IPv6:2001:470:b:84a   RELAY   # Net:  office
Connect:50.116.6.8            RELAY   # Host: glider
Connect:96.126.127.87         RELAY   # Host: kite
```

Method 2:

```
Connect:127                   OK
Connect:10.0.1                RELAY   # Net:  office
Connect:[IPv6:2001:470:b:84a] RELAY   # Net:  office
Connect:50.116.6.8            RELAY   # Host: glider
Connect:96.126.127.87         RELAY   # Host: kite
```

However whenever I try using either method 1 or 2, I am unable to relay e-mail messages through the host.

/var/log/maillog entry:

```
May 31 11:57:15 freshsalmon sm-mta[25500]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=[IPv6:2001:470:b:84a:223:6cff:fe80:35dc], arg2=IPv6:2001:470:b:84a:223:6cff:fe80:35dc, relay=[IPv6:2001:470:b:84a:223:6cff:fe80:35dc], reject=553 5.3.0 RELAY # Net:office
```

Test session from telnet:

```
syzdek@blackenhawk$ telnet -6 freshsalmon.office.example.com 25
Trying 2001:470:b:84a::69...
Connected to freshsalmon.office.bindlebinaries.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 office.example.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4; Thu, 31 May 2012 11:57:15 -0800
HELO blackenhawk.office.example.com
250 office.example.com Hello [IPv6:2001:470:b:84a:223:6cff:fe80:35dc], pleased to meet you
MAIL FROM:syzdek@example.com
553 5.3.0 RELAY # Net:office
```

What is the correct way to add an IPv6 address/network to the access file in sendmail?

Update: Apparently my access file was not working regardless.  Removing the comments at the end of the line seems to have fixed the problem.  Here is the lines which worked:

```
Connect:127                                     OK
Connect:IPv6:::1                                OK
# Net: office
Connect:10.0.1                                  RELAY
Connect:IPv6:2001:470:b:84a                     RELAY
# Host: glider
Connect:50.116.6.8                              RELAY
Connect:IPv6:2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fedf:381a     RELAY
# Host: kite
Connect:96.126.127.87                           RELAY
Connect:IPv6:2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fedf:52a4     RELAY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2001:470:b:84a isn't a valid IPv6 address by itself.  At a minimum it would need to be 2001:470:b:84a:: to indicate trailing zeroes - or the complete address that sendmail is indicating in the logs (2001:470:b:84a:223:6cff:fe80:35dc).

Once you have the address the first format you tried (IPV6:...) should work.

Comment: But I am trying to add an IPv6 network, not just a single host.  What is the correct syntax for a network? As an example, I can use "10.0.1" to add the network 10.0.1.0/24.

Comment: I see what you mean.  It may seem odd, but try fully expanding the /64 - so try IPv6:2001:0470:000b:084a (without brackets).

Comment: Okay, small confession. Apparently the comments at the end of the access statements are not valid. I've update my post to reflect the change.

Answer (score 1):

According to the examples from the [configuration README](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/), you should remove the brackets